# Highcharts displays series names but missing data points from json source

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, highcharts

I am using Highcharts with JSON data to render a standard line chart but am having some trouble getting the series data to display.  The chart frame and series names appear on the page and everything checks out in the console, so I know that it has succeeded in fetching the data.

The JSON output appears valid when I run through JSONLint so I'm a little confused as to why this chart will not render correctly.

Here is my chart **JAVASCRIPT CODE**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                zoomType: "x" 
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickInterval:  7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                labels: {
                    format: '{value:%b %e, %Y}',
                    rotation: -45
                },
            },
            yAxis: {
                allowDecimals: true,
                title: {
                    text: '$US'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                xDateFormat: '%b %e, %Y',
            },

            series: []
        }

        $.getJSON("mdb_ajax.php", function(json) {
            options.series = new Array();
            for(i=0;i< json.length;i++) {
                options.series.push(json[i]);
            }
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
```

Here's the corresponding **PHP FILE**:

```
$price_output = $prices->getPrices($filter_option);

    foreach($price_output as $category => $price)
    {
        $arr[] = array('name' => $category, 'data' => $price);
    }

print json_encode($arr);
```

As you can see I've jury-rigged the object to add "name" and "data" keys to aid Highcharts, but the object results in perfectly valid JSON without this additional work (it just won't display anything this way).

Here is a sample of the **JSON DATA**:

```
[
  {
    "name": "CTGY1",
    "data": {
        "1414998000000": "6.2400",
        "1415084400000": "-3.1110",
        "1415170800000": "1.5090",
        "1415257200000": "4.2390",
        "1415343600000": "1.6990",
        "1426140000000": "5.9100"
    },
    {
    "name": "CTGY2",
    "data": {
        "1414998000000": "7.7890",
        "1415084400000": "-0.7610",
        "1415170800000": "1.1600",
        "1415257200000": "5.3300",
        "1415343600000": "1.9290",
        "1415602800000": "-0.8260"
  }
]
```

I'm guessing there needs to be some definition of the key-values when processing the fetched JSON data, I'm just not sure what that would look like at this point.  Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` should be an array and the Y-values should not be strings in your case:
`data: [[1415602800000,-0.8260],[],...]`

here are the acceptable data structures for `data` within `series`
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series.data

Highcharts API also provide a few examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/data-array-of-arrays/

Comment: Thank you, I modified both of these issues and the data appeared.  As a side note I made use of JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK to force into numeric vs string, however this will not work in PHP < 5.3.3.